# Can't Create Content Type

Tags: drupal, module

This is from the node_example from the Examples module on Drupal.org, I cut most part of them off now this should be an edited version of node_example.install: http://newstartpoint.com/public/node_example.install.txt

Now this is what I managed to get by myself: This http://newstartpoint.com/public/tudou_update.install.txt. This above one works but the one I programmed doesn't. Can anyone give me some ideas? They seem pretty much identical.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say definitively if this is the issue (as I don't have you full module to test).  However, on line 18 in your file http://newstartpoint.com/public/tudou_update.install.txt

you don't have

```
'custom' => TRUE,
```

and the original does.

This documentation about it is a little confusing : http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_set_defaults/7

Otherwise the files are basically the same. Anything in the error logs?

Comment: Seems that after changing the base to 'node_content' it works.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39624/cant-create-content-type. Here's the answer. Thanks both of you :)